# Hosting a premium WordPress plugin on a server for auto-update purposes

Tags: php, wordpress

I followed a guide on how to host your (premium) plugin on a server for auto-updates. Everything is working, but it's not secure at all. The link to the plugin's ZIP is public and anyone can download it.

Here is how the update.php file (on my server) looks like:

```
if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
    switch ($_POST['action']) {
        case 'version':
            echo "3.1.1";
            break;
        case 'info':
            $obj                = new stdClass();
            $obj->slug          = '...';
            $obj->plugin_name   = '...';
            $obj->new_version = "3.1.0";
            $obj->requires      = '4.7';
            $obj->tested        = '4.7.3';
            $obj->downloaded    = 12540;
            $obj->last_updated  = '2017-02-12';
            $obj->homepage      = '...';
            $obj->sections      = array(
                'description' => '...'
            );
            $obj->download_link = 'https://.../latest.zip';
            echo serialize($obj);
            break;
        case 'license':
            echo 'false';
            break;
    }
} else {
    header('Cache-Control: public');
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/zip');
    readfile('latest.zip');
}
```

The script will always return the .zip file, if no POST parameter (version, info or license) is provided.

All I want is to have a parameter that is sent to update.php, when WordPress requests the new .zip, just so I can authorize the download.

Even if anyone knows where this process is documented, that would help a lot as well.

Comment: So you want to send a parameter via POST for authentication? but you are checking isset post so it never comes to else if you even send a extra param for authentication?

Comment: Either this, or I need to know how to make WP ask for the "license" POST parameter.

Answer (score 0):

This is how **WordPress** making `POST` request to its server when installing the new plugin.

`array (
  'method' => 'POST',
  'timeout' => 15,
  'redirection' => 5,
  'httpversion' => '1.0',
  'user-agent' => 'WordPress/4.7.3; http://example.com/',
  'reject_unsafe_urls' => false,
  'blocking' => true,
  'headers' => 
  array (
  ),
  'cookies' => 
  array (
  ),
  'body' => 
  array (
    'action' => 'plugin_information',
    'request' => 'O:8:"stdClass":4:{s:4:"slug";s:7:"jetpack";s:6:"fields";a:1:{s:8:"sections";b:0;}s:8:"per_page";i:24;s:6:"locale";s:5:"en_US";}',
  ),
  'compress' => false,
  'decompress' => true,
  'sslverify' => true,
  'sslcertificates' => '/var/www/html/wp2/wp-includes/certificates/ca-bundle.crt',
  'stream' => false,
  'filename' => NULL,
  'limit_response_size' => NULL,
)`

According to your question, you can verify users by his secure **token**(preferable) or email id

So whenever he install the plugin you need to create a secure token on your server and send it to your plugin then request plugin to store into the database(**wp_option** preferable) of WordPress after every calls to make to the server, You need to verify that token is valid else reject the request.

You need to change your code to verify the valid data coming on in **POST** rather than checking blindly **POST** data is available

You can send your token in header
Example : `Authorization: Basic dm9yZGVsOnZvcmRlbA==`